# regular expression with matching empty string

Tags: regular-language, string

I am working on a django project to modify database options in the file *settings.py*.I want to use  regular expression to do it.
the options just like :
 ***'PASSWORD':'123456',***
so I have write a function,the code is following:

```
    def config_item(self,data,item,value):
        rStr = "'"+item+"':(\s)?'\w*'"
        src = "'"+item+"': '"+value+"'"
        res = re.sub(rStr,src,data)
        return res
```

So I can call like this to modify password to '000000',

```
data = config_item(data,'PASSWORD','0000')
```

But when the source password is blank or dest password is blank ,it does not work.That is ,it does not match ***'PASSWORD':'',***
Are there some wrong with the regular expression.
How do I write it rightly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try using `'[^']*'` instead of `'\w*'`

I think \w is a bit more strict.